# (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1) is returning null

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use this template to create my first app using Database but I'm struck at this point. As seen in other solutions, there were no Errors like calling the function before setContentView(layout) or getting clean output on Project->Clean.

My Activity Java file is as follows

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  dbHelper = new CountriesDbAdapter(this);
  dbHelper.open();

  //Clean all data
  dbHelper.deleteAllCountries();
  //Add some data
  dbHelper.insertSomeCountries();

  //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
  displayListView(); /*Error Here*/ /*NULLreference Exception*/

 }
```

Error is thrown in the last line of the above code

Main java continued

```
private void displayListView() {


  Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllCountries();

  // The desired columns to be bound
  String[] columns = new String[] {
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CODE,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_NAME,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_CONTINENT,
    CountriesDbAdapter.KEY_REGION
  };

  // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
  int[] to = new int[] { 
    R.id.code,
    R.id.name,
    R.id.continent,
    R.id.region,
  };

  // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data 
  //as well as the layout information
  dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, R.layout.country_info, 
    cursor, 
    columns, 
    to,
    0);

  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  // Assign adapter to ListView
  listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter); /*NULLreference Exception*/
```

Main.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

 <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
  android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />

 <EditText android:id="@+id/myFilter" android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ems="10" 
  android:hint="@string/some_hint">
  <requestFocus />
 </EditText>

 <ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And Country_info.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Code: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:text="Continent: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="Region: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/continent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/region"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/continent"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/code"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Pretty much stuck here, No solution i've been searchin solved the problem :(

EDIT:

Adapter Class

```
public class CountriesDbAdapter {

 public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_CODE = "code";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_CONTINENT = "continent";
 public static final String KEY_REGION = "region";

 private static final String TAG = "CountriesDbAdapter";
 private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "World";
 private static final String SQLITE_TABLE = "Country";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 private final Context mCtx;

 private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
  "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + SQLITE_TABLE + " (" +
  KEY_ROWID + " integer PRIMARY KEY autoincrement," +
  KEY_CODE + "," +
  KEY_NAME + "," +
  KEY_CONTINENT + "," +
  KEY_REGION + "," +
  " UNIQUE (" + KEY_CODE +"));";

 private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
   super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }


  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   Log.w(TAG, DATABASE_CREATE);
   db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
     + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
   db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SQLITE_TABLE);
   onCreate(db);
  }
 }

 public CountriesDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
  this.mCtx = ctx;
 }

 public CountriesDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
  mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
  mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }

 public void close() {
  if (mDbHelper != null) {
   mDbHelper.close();
  }
 }

 public long createCountry(String code, String name, 
   String continent, String region) {

  ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
  initialValues.put(KEY_CODE, code);
  initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  initialValues.put(KEY_CONTINENT, continent);
  initialValues.put(KEY_REGION, region);

  return mDb.insert(SQLITE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
 }

 public boolean deleteAllCountries() {

  int doneDelete = 0;
  doneDelete = mDb.delete(SQLITE_TABLE, null , null);
  Log.w(TAG, Integer.toString(doneDelete));
  return doneDelete > 0;

 }

 public Cursor fetchCountriesByName(String inputText) throws SQLException {
  Log.w(TAG, inputText);
  Cursor mCursor = null;
  if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
   mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
     null, null, null, null, null);

  }
  else {
   mCursor = mDb.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
     KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
     KEY_NAME + " like '%" + inputText + "%'", null,
     null, null, null, null);
  }
  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;

 }

 public Cursor fetchAllCountries() {

  Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
    KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME, KEY_CONTINENT, KEY_REGION}, 
    null, null, null, null, null);

  if (mCursor != null) {
   mCursor.moveToFirst();
  }
  return mCursor;
 }

 public void insertSomeCountries() {

  createCountry("AFG","Afghanistan","Asia","Southern and Central Asia");
  createCountry("ALB","Albania","Europe","Southern Europe");
  createCountry("DZA","Algeria","Africa","Northern Africa");
  createCountry("ASM","American Samoa","Oceania","Polynesia");
  createCountry("AND","Andorra","Europe","Southern Europe");
  createCountry("AGO","Angola","Africa","Central Africa");
  createCountry("AIA","Anguilla","North America","Caribbean");

 }

}
```

All the dependancies had been imported...

EDIT 2:

Error Log:

```
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Process: com.somesample, PID: 1038
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.annahockeyleague.ourFamily/com.somesample.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
**04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.somesample.main.displayListView(main.java:71)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at com.somesample.main.onCreate(main.java:38)**
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-02 15:20:02.400: E/AndroidRuntime(1038):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Could you show the adapter class?

Comment: yes , its been included in the edit....

Comment: What does it print if you do `Log.d("LOG", String.valueOf(listView == null));` after the `findViewById` ?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace please?

Comment: Added the error log since the Error occured...

Comment: Have you already cleaned and rebuilt the app? Sometimes resource ids in R and binary XML files are out of sync.

Comment: what is the value of the listView if you move this line: ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1); after setContentView(R.layout.main); Is it still null?

Comment: @laalto Yes ... It is of no use.. Same error...

Comment: @Toorop displayListView() is only called after setContentView() in the above code?...

Comment: Can we see your AndroidManifest.xml? You get a lot of similar errors to `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.annahockeyleague.ourFamily/com.somesample.main}: java.lang.NullPointerException` when there is an issue with how Activities are declared in the manifest. It could be useful to see the class name for your main activity as well.

Comment: @Sharukh Mohamed I saw that, still I was curious if exactly after setting the content view, the reference is null. Have you tried to change the id?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If this is resolved don't forget to accept an answer. In this case you'll have to write up a quick answer yourself, and briefly explain how you fixed it and then accept your own answer. It will help anyone who stumbles across this question later.

Comment: Yes, I actually tried using @android:id/list , it dint work as well..

Comment: is your activity extending directly the Activity class from android?
or do you have another class between them?

Comment: The answer was sorted out.. Will post it in 8 hrs... Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem sometimes is that you could've build an activity via the Eclipse IDE and working on the frame xml and reference your activity XML .

If You are working with frames then be sure to link it back to the activity with this piece of code

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_some_xml, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
```

at the end of your activity class